# Emotion theming with TypeScript: Property 'X' does not exist on type 'object'. ts(2339)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, emotion

I can't find a way to make Emotion theming work with TypeScript.

```js
import React from "react";
import { ThemeProvider } from "emotion-theming";
import styled from "@emotion/styled";

const theme = {
  colors: {
    gray: "#ccc",
  },
};

const MyComponent = styled.div((props) => ({
  color: props.theme.colors.gray,
}));

const App = () => (
  <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
    <MyComponent />
  </ThemeProvider>
);

export default App;
```

The docs says: "By default, props.theme has an any type annotation and works without any errors". But I have one on `props.theme.colors.gray`: **Property 'colors' does not exist on type 'object'.ts(2339)**

Am I missing something here?

Comment: I checked in here the `theme` seems to be an object: https://github.com/emotion-js/emotion/tree/master/packages/emotion-theming#api

Comment: Yes, `theme` should be an object (which is the case here) or a function returning an object. I don't know why TS is complaining.

Comment: can you make a codesandbox recreating this? I'm not sure I'd be able to solve it but I am keen to see what's going on

Answer (score 8):

Emotion 11 simplified this.

Define your Theme in an `emotion.d.ts` file

```
   declare module '@emotion/react' {
      export interface Theme {
        colors : {
          primary: string;
          secondary: string;
        };
      }
    }
```

This provides an override for the empty `Theme` interface within Emotion.

https://emotion.sh/docs/typescript#define-a-theme

Comment: And where do you put this file and how to use it? The docs are not clear to me.

Comment: @Ini I've added an answer continuing on this answering your question.

Answer (score 2):

Continuing on @chatian's helpful answer, after you've made the .d.ts file, then put it somewhere in your project, e.g., in the "src" folder, and specify it as an "ambient file" to be used by the TS runtime of your editor by adding its directory path, i.e. `"src"`, in the `"include"` array of your `tsconfig.json` file.

Now you should be able to use both your own types and import the types you extend from emotion in your tsx files, e.g., `import { Theme } from "@emotion/react"`.

An example codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/9z2md?file=/src/global.d.ts

Notice since the Theme type in the above example is not "extending" emotion's Theme type then you don't need to import it at all and you have access to it globally.

(note: this sandbox was not created by me so credit goes to [nerdyman](https://codesandbox.io/u/nerdyman).)